# EF6: Mapping entity with complex type to one table

Tags: entity-framework

I have a entity that have a complex type and I'm using CodeFirst like this:

```
public class Session
{
    public int SessionId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public Folder SessionFolder { get { set; } 

}

public class Folder
{
    string _path;

    public Folder(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
    }
}
```

I'm using Fluent API and I'd like to make only one table, Session table with this struct:

```
SessionId as int
CreationDate as datetime
Path as nvarchar(255)
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework 6 you can specify in which tables an entity is saved, via the DbContext:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext() : base("YourContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Session> Sessions{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Folder> Folders{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Saves the Session and folder in the same table, but allows for individual fetches
        modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().HasRequired(s => s.Folder).WithRequiredPrincipal();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().ToTable("SessionFolderTable");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Folder>().ToTable("SessionFolderTable");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jan. But there are two important qüestions; in my design a SessionFolder only has visibility in the context of the Session. Also, Folder can exist in other class like Document and obviously I'll create the table Document and I'll want that the Path property is in the same table.

Is possible with this code??